# Hcatalog hive issue java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI: does not have a scheme

Tags: hive, hcatalog

hi i am trying to do this hcatalog example from the following link.

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-2-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_19_6.html

i am getting the following exception when i run the job.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI:  does not have a scheme

java class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
import org.apache.hcatalog.common.*;
import org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hcatalog.data.*;
import org.apache.hcatalog.data.schema.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
//import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;

public class UseHCat extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static class Map extends Mapper<WritableComparable, HCatRecord, Text, IntWritable> {
        String groupname;

        @Override
      protected void map( WritableComparable key,
                          HCatRecord value,
                          org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<WritableComparable, HCatRecord,
                          Text, IntWritable>.Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // The group table from /etc/group has name, 'x', id
            groupname = (String) value.get(0);
            int id = (Integer) value.get(2);
            // Just select and emit the name and ID
            context.write(new Text(groupname), new IntWritable(id));
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable,
                                       WritableComparable, HCatRecord> {

        protected void reduce( Text key,
                               java.lang.Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                               org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<Text, IntWritable,
                               WritableComparable, HCatRecord>.Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // Only expecting one ID per group name
            Iterator<IntWritable> iter = values.iterator();
            IntWritable iw = iter.next();
            int id = iw.get();
            // Emit the group name and ID as a record
            HCatRecord record = new DefaultHCatRecord(2);
            record.set(0, key.toString());
            record.set(1, id);
            context.write(null, record);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = getConf();
        args = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs(); 

        // Get the input and output table names as arguments
        String inputTableName = args[0];
        String outputTableName = args[1];
        // Assume the default database
        String dbName = "hadooppracticedb";

        Job job = new Job(conf, "UseHCat");
        HCatInputFormat.setInput(job, InputJobInfo.create(dbName,
                inputTableName, null));
        job.setJarByClass(UseHCat.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        // An HCatalog record as input
        job.setInputFormatClass(HCatInputFormat.class);

        // Mapper emits a string as key and an integer as value
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        // Ignore the key for the reducer output; emitting an HCatalog record as value
        job.setOutputKeyClass(WritableComparable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(DefaultHCatRecord.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(HCatOutputFormat.class);

        HCatOutputFormat.setOutput(job, OutputJobInfo.create(dbName,
                   outputTableName, null));
        HCatSchema s = HCatOutputFormat.getTableSchema(job);
        System.err.println("INFO: output schema explicitly set for writing:" + s);
        HCatOutputFormat.setSchema(job, s);
        return (job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new UseHCat(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

getting exception at this line

```
HCatInputFormat.setInput(job, InputJobInfo.create(dbName,
            inputTableName, null));
```

hadoop jar command:

hadoop jar Hcat.jar com.otsi.hcat.UseHCat -files $HCATJAR -libjars ${LIBJARS} groups groupids

i have set the following property in hive-site.xml

hive-site.xml:

```
<property>
        <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
        <value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
    </property>
```

i have created the 2 tables groups groupids in "hadooppracticedb"..

please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined metastore local property?

You should only set the hive.metastore.uris property if you are running a standalone MetaStore server, in which case you need to set hive.metastore.local=false and set hive.metastore.uris to a Thrift URI.

Please see this document for more details:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+MetastoreAdmin

Comment: Hi,I am using hive-0.13.0..hive.metastore.uris
Hive connects to one of these URIs to make metadata requests to a remote Metastore (comma separated list of URIs)
hive.metastore.local
local or remote metastore (Removed as of Hive 0.10: If hive.metastore.uris is empty local mode is assumed, remote otherwise  ..and im running this example on a 2 node cluster..

Comment: hive-site.xml;<property>
        <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
        <value>thrift://NameNode:9083</value>
    </property>